# Parse XML in react-redux-promise app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers, redux-promise

The data source for my app only provides data in XML format.

I use axios to get the XML data. It ends up as a string in the data section of the result.

I have tried to use xml2js to convert it, but it just fires off a async job and returns, so I dont get the redux-promise middelware to work. The payload is nothing when the reducers sends the data to the component that should render it.

Not sure if this makes sense, but can I make the reducer wait for the new function call to return before sending the data on the the component?

action index.js

```
export function fetchData(jobid, dest) {
    const url = `${DATA_URL}jobid=${jobid}&refdist=${dest}`;
    const request = axios.get(url);

    console.log(request);

    return {
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

my reducer

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
    console.log(action);

    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
            console.log("pre");
            parseString(action.payload.data, function (err, result) {
                // Do I need some magic here??? or somewhere else?
                console.dir(result);
            });

        return [action.payload.data, ...state];
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: I know the reducer code is not correct as it returns the unconverted XML string, but what should I return? or can I stop the reducer from returning until the parseString function has returned?

Comment: The reducer shouldn't parse. The reducer takes an action and the old state to make a new state. Its job is not to fetch or convert anything. If you could pause your reducer would you want to lock up the entire browser page until it's done? Wait until you have all the data ready and only then dispatch an action to put this into your app state. And this includes async parsing of the data.

Comment: Use Redux-Thunk for async actions. Or use Redux-Saga (be prepared for a learning curve).

Comment: In your reducer, FETCH_DATA should be return ...state first, not last. so it should be `return [...state, action.payload.data]` your updated state is being overwritten by the old state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should change your action creator code, because axios is async. And dispatch action after receive data.
You don't need this logic in reducer.
For async actions you may use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

```
export const fetchData = (jobid, dest)=>dispatch =>{
    const url = `${DATA_URL}jobid=${jobid}&refdist=${dest}`;

    const request = axios.get(url).then(res=>{
        parseString(res, function (err, result) {
           if(result){
                dispatch({
                   type: FETCH_DATA,
                   data:result
                })
            }
            if(err) throw err
        });
    }).catch(err=>console.error(error))

};
///clean reducer
export default function (state = [], action) {
     switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA:
        return [...state, action.data ];
    }
    return state;
}
```

Also you may need to know about fetching process: loading, success , failure.Then action creator may looks like:

```
export const fetchData = (jobid, dest)=>dispatch =>{
 const url = `${DATA_URL}jobid=${jobid}&refdist=${dest}`;
    dispatch({
       type: FETCH_DATA_REQUEST,
       data:result,
       isFetching:true
    })
    const request = axios.get(url).then(res=>{
        parseString(res, function (err, result) {
           if(result){
                dispatch({
                   type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
                   data:result,
                   isFetching:false
                })
            }
            if(err) throw err
        });
    }).catch(err=>{
        dispatch({
           type: FETCH_DATA_FAILURE,
           err:err,
           isFetching:false
        })
        console.error(error)
    })

};
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me futher on my way :) Great explanation.

Comment: you are welcome) you can ask any questions online on this [chat](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103538784460615680)

Comment: mine is exact same issue, i am struggling, let me change my code this way. Thanks.

Comment: @Utro, mine is also same issue, but its existing code and it uses promise,export function getXmlData() {


  debug('starting action');  

  return {
    type:    'GET_XML_DATA',
    promise: request.get(API_URL)
  }
};

Comment: can you tell me for promise how should i change it?